# Can not connect to the internet from fresh install windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, dhcp

So I reformatted a existing computer (Which was on win7) with Win10. I can not for the life of me connect to the internet though. I have tried the following:

- /release
- /renew
- Tried setting my ipv4 address manually - when i did that and restarted my computer, it got set back to obtain automatically.
- manufacture resetting my router (Dark Knight RT-N66U)
- upgrading router to latest firmware
- uninstalling the NEC drivers and re-installing
- i can ping 127.0.0.1
- i can not ping the router 192.168.1.1
- this is the same machine i used with win7 just reformatted with win10 and yes the internet was working on windows 7.
- *also have multiple other machines on my network - some windows -some mac -all work fine wired or wireless.

and countless of other things but cant even think off the top of my head right now.

Output of ipconfig /all

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-9NPA4PQ
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No 

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Generic Marvell Yukon 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.12.135(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


Tunnel adapter isatap.{76F4ECFF-9996-47DF-91DF-89E71E99A8AB}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the driver you installed for Ethernet adapter is compatible with Windows 10 ? You are getting APIPA, is DHCP service working ?

Comment: when i uninstall the drivers. and scan for hardware changes again via the device manager it seems to install them again... ? is that normal?

Comment: blah was not thinking about how old my comp is since it still rocks. But that might be my issue. 
ASUS P6X58D Premium
does not look like they are supporting 10 at all. only see bios updates to 8.1 
might try to buy a Network card and see what other trouble I find myself running into... Not a mission critical machine. so whatever. more for gaming F'in around.